# Friendly url creation FLUID

Tags: typo3, friendly-url, fluid

I'm developping a TYPO3 extension (TYPO3 6.2) and I'm trying to create a link with parameters.

My working link is like this:

```
........./?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

Now I'm trying to make this url more friendly and want to show it as:

```
........./val1/val2
```

but when I access this url, I have a TYPO3 error saying:

```
Reason: Segment "val1" was not a keyword for a postVarSet as expected on page with id=MYID.
```

The url is created with FLUID:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="MYID" additionalParams="{tagid: '{var.id}'}">More</f:link.page>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Fluid, but missing RealURL config, there are two good articles written by Dmitry Dulepov - RealURL author:

- http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2008/05/realurl-made-easy-part-1.html
- http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2008/06/realurl-made-easy-part-2.html